# PHP - Contact Form Not Working

Tags: php, html, contact-form

Can you tell me why this code is not working? This is a basic PHP - HTML contact form...

```
<?php 
    $errors = array();

    if (isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'])) {

        $name  = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']));
        $email = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']));
        $ip    = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        if (empty($name) || empty($email)) {
          $errors[] = '<div id="error">All fields are required.</div>';
        } 

        if (strlen($name)>25 || strlen($email)>1024) {
          $errors[] = '<div id="error">One or more fields exceeded the character limit.</div><br />';
        } 

        if (empty($errors)) {
            function email($to, $subject, $body) {
                mail($to, $subject, $body, 'From: support@astrominds.in');
            }
            email("abc@xyz.com", "Contact Message"," Your Subject: $subject\n" . "Ip: $ip\n" . " Your Name: $name\n" . " Your Email: $email\n");
        } 
    }
?>
```

This is the html form...

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
    <label class="label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="detail"  autocapitalize="words" autocorrect="off">

    <label class="label">Email</label>
    <input type="text" id="f1" class="detail" name="email" autocapitalize="words" autocorrect="off" />

    <input type="submit" value="Continue" class="csssubmit" >
```

Comment: If you tell us _in what way_ it's not working, we may be able to tell you why.

Comment: It keeps showing me error messages like "All the fields are required... etc." even when everything is correct!

Comment: You're not showing any code that would actually display the error messages. Please include all relevant code.

Comment: *Umm...*, why the SQL? If that's your actual code, ask yourself why. So, is that your actual/full code?

Comment: Here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: *Oh,* and you're missing a closing `</form>` tag. Too many possible errors to put in an actual answer; fearing I will be opening up a can of you know what.

Comment: First off, it's unclear as to what you're trying to achieve.

You have SQL code but not mentioning if you're using this in conjunction with a database; yet alone if you've successfully connected.

You're also missing a closing `</form>` tag which will break your code. So, please be clear and concise. Voted to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code contains several mistakes. I just removed all those.

Try this:

->Input field has no name field. i set it in form. you can also pass this as string inside your code.

->You are not set $subject field yet ,but you are trying to access values from this and this will make error in mail sending fiel (inside mail()).

->Don't need to check post values for each values just set what i did with form submit type name.

-> pls try to use form tags to process input form fields

```
<?php 
    $errors = array();

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $name       =   htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']));
    $email      =   htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']));
    $ip         =   $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if (empty($name) || empty($email)) 
        {
          $errors[] = '<div id="error">All fields are required.</div>';
        } 

    if ( strlen($email)>1024)
        {
          $errors[] = '<div id="error">One or more fields exceeded the character limit.</div><br />';
        } 

    if (empty($errors)) {
    function email($to, $subject, $body) 
    {
      mail($to, $subject, $body, 'support@astrominds.in');
    }
    email("abc@xyz.com","Contact Message", "Your Subject: Type subject\n" , "Ip: $ip\n"."Your Name: $name\n"."Your Email: $email\n");
    echo "Form Works Success";
    } 
    }
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="formnot.php">
    <label class="label">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" id="f1" class="detail" name="email" autocapitalize="words" autocorrect="off" />
    <label class="label">Name</label>
                    <input type="text"  name="name"  />


        <input type="submit" value="Continue" class="csssubmit" name="submit" >
        </form>
```